# Add post->ID into wordpress function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wp database function for a lack of better wording. It does the standard INSERT to database and UPDATE database. I need to use post->ID as a column.

[image]

I cant get it to insert the `post->ID` where post_id is.. here is the function...

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'brash_add_settings' );
```

function brash_add_settings($post_id) {

```
     // Add slider
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    // Get WPDB Object
    global $wpdb;

    // Table name
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "brash";

    // Create new record
    if($_POST['key'] == 0) {            

    // Execute query
        $wpdb->query(
            $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO $table_name
                                (post_id, name, data, date_c, date_m)
                            VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %d, %d)",
                            '',
                            '',
                            time(),
                            time()
                            )
        );

        // Empty slider
        $slider = array();

        // ID
        $id = mysqli_insert_id();
    } else {

        // Get slider
        $slider = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1" , ARRAY_A);

        // ID
        $id = $slider['id'];

        $slider = json_decode($slider['data'], true);
    }


    // DB data
    $post = $post->ID;
    $name = $wpdb->escape($slider['properties']['backgroundimage']);
    $data = $wpdb->escape(json_encode($slider));

    // Update
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $table_name SET
                post_id = '$post',
                name = '$name',
                data = '$data',
                date_m = '".time()."'
              ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

    // Echo last ID for redirect
    echo $id;

    die();
}



}
```

Nothing special here, but I assume its not getting the id because maybe the hook is `admin_init`? I am just not sure where to look in terms of getting the id to post to the database...

Comment: Is it wanted that in the prepare statement you have five placeholders but only four actual values? Where does `$post` come from?

Comment: I actually found a solution, I store the post id into a form then when its submitted that value populates the post_id column.. ill update this question with my solution soon, I need to catch a quick nap..

Answer (score 0):

It was impossible to use `post->ID` inside my function, but inside my form I could echo the `post->ID` because it's inside a metabox on the post. Inputs are great for storing data.

```
<div class="post-id">
 <input type="text" name="thepostid" value="<?php echo the_ID() ?>" id="someid">
</div>
```

I use jQuery and ajax to take the data, here is a snippet.

```
 jQuery('.post-id input').each(function() {

        // Save original name attr to element's data
        jQuery(this).data('name', jQuery(this).attr('name') );

        jQuery(this).attr('name', 'brash-post-id[postid]['+jQuery(this).attr('name')+']');
    });
```

A snippet of adding it to ajax.

```
            // Data to send
            $data = $data.add( jQuery('.post-id').find('input') );

            // Post layer
            jQuery.ajax(jQuery(el).attr('action'), {
                type : 'POST',
                data : $data.serialize(),
                async : false,
                success : function(id)
```

Then using it in the form submit to database function.

```
 //Changing the UPDATE query from op

 $slider['postid'] = $_POST['brash-post-id']['postid']; //This is added on


 // DB data 

    $post_id = $wpdb->escape($slider['postid']['thepostid']); //['thepostid'] is the name of the input
    $name = $wpdb->escape($slider['properties']['title']); // The title of an input field
    $data = $wpdb->escape(json_encode($slider)); // all of the data

    // Update
    //$slider['postid']['thepostid'] is inserted as $post_id, which is post->ID
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $table_name SET
                post_id = '$post_id', 
                name = '$name',
                data = '$data',
                date_m = '".time()."'
              ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```